# Generate a signed APK with its database from a website

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it possible to create a website that generate a signed APK and embed a dynamically SQLite database to it depending of the data inserted on the website ?

**If yes, what is the best way to implement it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a piece of work, but can be done (technically) quite easy.
But it's not a weekend project.

First, I'd suggest you use a build server like Jenkins or Atlassian Bamboo which will do the Build/APK signing for you.
Advantages: You have zipped artifacts as output from the build server which contain your signed apk.

What you need to do is
- Create the website, let the user enter the data
- In the backend, after the user clicked "submit" you have to create your sqlite db
- copy the sqlite db to the assets folder of the android studio project
- start the jenkins/bamboo job
- wait until it's finished
- grab the artifact
- provide the download link to the user

Technically not rocket science, but quite some work.

**be aware that the apk is signed with YOUR key/keystore**

hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I understood most of this answer but can you clarify the Jenkins/Atlassian part, how the app will be built and signed ? is there any tutorial out there for this specific problem ?

Comment: This is where I meant "not a weekend project". you can look at www.atlassian.com or https://jenkins.io/ to start reading about build servers. basically they run "jobs" that start the compiler. Build Server Administrator is a job description :) --- You will need a bit to get into it - my company uses bamboo and is quite happy with it. costs only $10 per year in the smallest edition. jenkins is open source/free but i find bamboo easier to use. Your choice.

Comment: A last question, why should I be aware about that last sentence you said : "be aware that the apk is signed with YOUR key/keystore" will it cause any problem ?

Comment: I said this because I am honestly not sure what happens if the same private key store is used to deploy multiple apps from different developers/dev accounts to the play store.
I have only one software label running, only one keystore and all my apps are published on the same account. I do not know, whether google will have to say something against that - I posted it just to make you think, in case you plan something like a "get your signed apk for free" for everyone-service. Read google publisher docs about signing and the real meaning of the key certificate.

Comment: To get you on the safe side, I'd suggest you put some "register account" to your website and create a unique certificate for each registered user. So each user has its own key from your server and you dont need to worry. Same as you copy the sqlite db to the build project, you copy the keystore for the user to the project before you start the build job. So you'd be even able to sign with unique certificates per user.

Comment: Oh I see that's a little tricky, but I got the general idea.
Thank you for this answer !